# Reverse animation before it is finished

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a button and when the user touches down and holds a popup appears. However, when the user releases his thumb before the pop animation finishes I'd like the animation to stop where it is and autoreverse to the initial position. How can I accomplish this?

Currently I'm simply using `UIView`s `-animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`. Do I have to set the animations explicitly in this case?

I've already tried reading the current state from the `presentationLayer` properties, but that somehow didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the second animation using the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option. This will stop the first animation if it's still running.

Comment: When I use this in conjunction with an animation that's based on a `CGAffineTransform` the transform effect does not reverse correctly (appears to be some random fluctuations in the reverse transform). Basically the same problem as when I take the current transform from the `representationLayer`.